# Having an error on the SIT when adding information (Oracle eBS 11i)

Tags: oracle

Good day all,

When inserting data in the SIT as shown in the screenshot below i get the following error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhoc4.png)

I've no idea about the origin of this error. I've tried to remove all the value set from the related KFF segment without success. Here after the text of the error (the error is not listed in MOS nor Google) :

> APP-FND-01564: ORACLE error 1722 in FDFICD
>   Cause:  FDFICD failed due to ORA-01722: invalid number.

The SQL statement being executed at the time of the error was: `INSERT INTO PER_ANALYSIS_CRITERIA(ENABLED_FLAG, SUMMARY_FLAG, START_DATE_ACTIVE, END_DATE_ACTIVE, LAST_UPDATE_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, SEGMENT1, SEGMENT2, SEGMENT3, REQUEST_ID, ID_FLEX_NUM, ANALYSIS_CRITERIA_ID) VALUES ('Y', :sumflg, to_date(:sdate, 'J'), to_date(:edate, 'J'), SYSDATE, :user_id, :SEGMENT1, :SEGMENT2, :SEGMENT3, :REQUEST_ID, :ID_FLEX_NUM, :ANALYSIS_CRITERIA_ID)` and was executed from the file &ERRFILE.

Thank you for your help,

Regards,

Moussa

Comment: The error is clear: you passed in a string whereas you should have passed in a number. You'll need to verify the parameters one by one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, The code is generated by the system, I've only setup the KFF. I've created another simple KFF with only one field and the error still appearing.